# VS2019 trying to add a reference comes up with "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2019

VS2019 trying to add a reference comes up with "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component". I have had a look at other posts and tried one thing but nothing working to date.
If it matters I have added a library called GroupDocs that you can use to compare 2 pdf's, no idea if this a com component. Been working fine for ages. Decided I also want to add a new reference for a new scenario (if you need to know I want add a reference to Excel so I can automate the process of comparing 2 Excel files this time) but cannot add a reference.

I haven't tried much to be honest.

- I tried closing VS and deleting the .vs folder and reopening but that didn't resolve the issue, it just recreate the .vs folder.
- Deleted all the files in ComponentModelCache folder (AppData/Local/Microsoft/VisualStudio/16_XXXXXX/) had no effect, when I opened VS again it recreated all the cache files.

The other ideas I have read I got no idea about so please break it
down to me in simple steps something to try.

Answer (score 0):

I take no credit other than the art of going thru the motions creating a ticket, stepping back and trusting the process of searching and searching until you find something that works.
https://learningintheopen.org/2021/05/31/visual-studio-v2019-add-reference-error-hresult-e_fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component/

I wish someone could explain how this happened.

If it helps anyone in this post it mentions check the gacutil by using the -l switch and it suggests you should get a response back saying Number of items = 1, mine said 0 but it worked also.